# Facing authentication problem with Google App Script - Oauth

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth

I created an app and deployed it using google app script, The users are now getting a message when they try to use the app -

"The developer of the tool needs your permission to access your data in Google."  Is there any way to not have this message show up and make the tool still work ?

I am confused and panicking right now everyone in the company thinks they are sharing thier google drive with me.

Please dont give me any hate for posting this here, I am new to app scripts trying to learn.

Tried removing Oauth and that caused the script to fail.

Comment: You can't remove this message, but it could help to specify exact scope you are asking in your code, in order to reassure users that you are not using all of their datas

Answer (score 1):

Users need to consent to your application accessing their data. You cant access it until they consent.

They are right your app does have access to their data and technically so do you depending upon what your app does. Thats why we need to trust the developers of these apps.